# Separating user and admin accounts safer?

Tags: mysql, database, security, database-design

So currently I'm working on a web application for a game and stumbled upon the following "problem"/question: Is it actually safer to have an individual table for the players/users and administrators?

Personally I think it's not and storing them both in one table would also be easier and more efficient, since every administrator is considered a player as well, but some people tell me it's safer to separate them without a clear reason why.

As for now I have them both stored in one table and am using a role based permission system.

Comment: Passwords stored as clear text or hash? How does client communicate to server? Missing a `tag` or two.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you need to worry about you player table getting compromised, then your administrator table would probably be equally at risk. There's nothing wrong with using one table from a design/security perspective. Database security has very little to do with which table data is held in.

Comment: Which administrator role(s) are you thinking about? MySQL administration or game administration? Should those be kept separate too? That's likely a good idea. Keeping the game admins separate from the players may well be a good idea; the game admins doing work as game admins should not be playing at the same time — probably. But it is feasible to have them play while administering (though it isn't likely to be good for them — they'll be distracted and will suffer, making administration mistakes or losing in the game through not concentrating on it).  You can do things whichever way you like.

Comment: Jonathan they can always pad their scores anyway :)

Comment: @DrewPierce players of administrative users could be linked to them to prevent those users from modifying their own data.

Comment: If i was an adminstrator i could just update data and unlock the Mystical Staff of Rohr

Comment: I was thinking of "game administrators" more along the lines of GMs, not actual technical adminstrators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By separating them you could control permissions to the tables with more granularity, for example limiting access to the administrators table to only certain database user accounts (so that it cannot be accessed by "game" code/servers at all).

But outside of those kinds of scenarios, I can't really think of one and agree with the second comment to your question.

Comment: What if other security is so awful that users just drop tables?